# Symfony2: Behaviour of error_bubbling with Collection

Tags: symfony

If have a form with an entity which holds a collection and I can't keep the errors from bubbling up to the Collection Level.

Example:
Entity ProductBundle holds a Collection of Product Entities. The Product Entity has the fields *name* and *price*.
When the fields contain errors, they show up at the Collection level.

Visualization:

> *ProductBundle*
>
> Name: SuperpricyBundle
>  Available_Until: 2018/1
>
> Included Products:
> *(<– default error placement , despite `error_bubbling = false`)*
>
> ---
>
> *(<– possible error placement at the Collection Entity Level)*
>   Position: 1
> Name: Coffee Machine
> Price: -50.00 <– **Error!!** *(<– possible error placement at the Collection Entity Level)*
>
> ---
>
> Position: 2
> Name: 6 Cups
> Price: 20.00

I can set `error_bubbling => false` on all levels (Entity level, Collection level, Collection Entity level), the errors keep bubbling up to the Collection level.
Shouldn't it be possible to prevent the bubbling AND/OR to bubble up to the Collection Entity level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in a different place. It has to do with how Symfony handles form inputs.

My form collection was dynamic. I added new items (included Products) with new indices, starting with an arbitrary high number, like 111111: If the last stored element has the input index `[4]`, the next inserted would be `111111`, the next `111112` and so on.
I did this because of side effects with other users:

If you have 3 items stored `[0]...[2]` and you add in your form a new item with index `[3]` and submit, in the meantime another user cou have inserted a new item, too, which will be indexed as `[3]` and hence replaced.

I couldn't fix this problem yet.
But setting arbitrary high indices doesn't work. Symfony always counts from `[0]` to all existing entities `[n]`, and the first added item will have the index `[n+1]`. This at least applies to form errors.

> An Error from form input with `name='myform_mycollection_[500]_field'` will
>   after submission and `$form->handleRequest(..)` be the error from form input
>   `name='myform_mycollection_[n+1]_field'`!